# Symfony crea mal las entidades

Tags: symfony

Estoy comenzando a aprender Symfony, y tengo un problema a la hora de crear una entidad con make:entity, al crearse la entidad me la crea con un monton de errores donde deberian estar las anotaciones. Les paso la entidad:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\BookRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: BookRepository::class)]
class Book
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $title;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 512, nullable: true)]
    private $image;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImage(): ?string
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function setImage(?string $image): self
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

He buscado alguna solucion pero no la he podido encontrar. Les estaria agradecido si me pudieran ayudar.

Comment: aparentemente no parece un error. las anotaciones estan, eso si, para la version php8 y superiores. quizas tienes otra version?

Comment: Indicanos que error te da, que version de symfony y de doctrine utilizas... para poder orientar mejor la respuesta. Como te digo, el formato es correcto, y la entidad es correcta...

Comment: aaah ok, muchas gracias. No sabia que las anotaciones en php 8 se hacian tambien de esa manera, sucede que estoy siguiendo un curso y las anotaciones ahi estan de manera diferente, ademas tambien en la documentacion de symfony tambien estan de manera diferente con este formato:
/**
*
*/
  Y tambien me deje llevar por el IDE que me marcaba error.
Muchas gracias por tu comentario!

Comment: solo por aclarar, el concepto de "anotaciones" anterior (el de /** @...)  viene porque en php no existian esos tags, y aunque se les llamaba asi, en realidad son comentarios y un analizador de estos para definirlos como "anotaciones". En php8 ya se introducen con un formato estandar ( el de #[] ) Si estas haciendo algun curso, verifica que estas utilizando versiones actualizadas (no te vayas a versiones 4 o inferiores) ya en 5 y 6 se van a utilizar como minimo php8.